# How to nullify all columns in subtotal/grand total rows that are left joined

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table like this:

| code_id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.00 |
| 1 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 50.00 |
| 2 | 50.00 |

And a code description table which tells you what the code means

| code_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Monthly fee |
| 2 | Yearly fee |

When I do a MySQL query to get the sum by code:

```
SELECT transaction.code_id, SUM(transaction.amount), description.name
FROM transaction LEFT JOIN description on description.code_id = transaction.code_id, 
GROUP BY code WITH ROLLUP;
```

I get this:

| code_id | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monthly Fee | 20.00 |
| 2 | Yearly Fee | 100.00 |
| null | **Yearly Fee** | 120.00 |

Notice how the grand total row uses a random value in the "description" table , but I want it to be null or called "grand total". Same applies to subtotals if I'm grouping by multiple fields.

FYI: I'm using MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `description.name` is not included in the group by, it is really the equivalent of an aggregate function that is something like `ANY(description.name)`, this is applied to all rows, including your total row, so you are getting a random value in the total. The way to avoid this is to include `description.name` in your group by. This will result in further sub-totals though, which I guess you don't want, but these can be excluded with `HAVING`,e.g.

```
SELECT t.code_id, d.name, SUM(t.amount)
FROM `transaction` AS t
  LEFT JOIN description AS d ON  d.code_id = t.code_id
GROUP BY t.code_id, d.name WITH ROLLUP
  HAVING d.name IS NOT NULL OR t.code_id IS NULL;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5_jDNSIg)**

*N.B. on later versions of MySQL this is probably better handled with `GROUPING()` e.g.*

```
SELECT t.code_id, d.name, SUM(t.amount)
FROM `transaction` AS t
  LEFT JOIN description AS d ON  d.code_id = t.code_id
GROUP BY t.code_id, d.name WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(t.code_id) = GROUPING(d.name);
```